# Event Category Filter with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a filter for my event category. It would display each events based on the category selected. But it failed to work.

Whenever a category is selected, the event displayed should be for the category selected alone and not all events.

My Event Filter code:

```
const EventSearchFilter: React.FC<IEventSearchFilterProps> = ({
  eventData,
}) => {
  const { data: categories } = useGetCategories();

  const uniqueCategories = useMemo(() => {
    const categoriesId = [
      ...new Set(eventData?.map((event) => event.categories).flat()),
    ];
    const eventCategories = categoriesId?.map((id) => {
      return categories
        ?.filter((cat) => cat.id === id)
        .map((filtered) => ({
          id,
          name: filtered.name,
          value: filtered.slug,
        }));
    });
    return eventCategories?.flat().flat();
  }, [eventData, categories]);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    
  };
  const handleSearch = () => {};
return (
    <StyledEventSearch>
      <Container>
        <Form>
          <Row>
            <Col xl={5} lg={5} md={6} sm={12}>
              <InputGroup>
                <AppInput
                  onChange={handleSearch}
                  placeholder={'Search for event'}
                  icon={<AiOutlineSearch />}
                />
              </InputGroup>
            </Col>

            <Col xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={4}>
              <Form.Group>
                <SelectInput
                  placeholder="Select Industry"
                  onChange={handleSelect}
                >
                  {uniqueCategories}
                </SelectInput>
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={4}>
              <Form.Group>
                <SelectInput
                  placeholder="Select Location"
                  onChange={handleSelect}
                >
                  {SELECT_INPUT_DATA}
                </SelectInput>
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={4}>
              <Form.Group>
                <SelectInput placeholder="Select Month" onChange={handleSelect}>
                  {SELECT_INPUT_DATA}
                </SelectInput>
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </StyledEventSearch>
  );
};

export default EventSearchFilter;
```

Maybe there's something I'm doing in the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: Hi mbc. Welcome to Stack Overflow . Can you reproduce this example in a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    category: '',
  }); 

const displayProduct = data
.filter(prod =>
    prod.category.includes(filters.category) 
  )
.map(data => {
    return(
        <div class="" key={data.id}>
             WHAT YOU WANT TO SHOW
        </div>
    )
}) 

<input type='radio'  onClick={() => {setFilters({...filters,category: 'YOUR CATEGORY',})}}/><label>YOUR CATEGORY</label>
```

Comment: didn't work well for the code.